# Update Polymer element?

Tags: ajax, polymer, element, reload

It's possible update a polymer element without reload page?
If I do this with ajax, I have the error "a type with that name is already registered".
What I can do?

Comment: Why do you need update the element? Show us what are you trying to do.

Comment: this element contain also a php code to do SQL query; there is a variable that changes with a SESSION or, if exists, with a GET; if I send a GET the first time I see the page normally but the second time I have that error and I see the element with old values.

Comment: Php works in server side, to do what you want I think you should use javascript instead php. That is the reason why you need reload the page. Maybe you will need to rethink about of how to solve your problem using all the functionalities that Polymer´s gives.

Comment: I have to do SQL queries to have the information that the element shows; I have thought to pass the value creating an attribute of polymer element but I can't catch it with php code.

Comment: How about to use ajax and javascript to do that? To change properties of your element you probably need to use data binding. I think that your question must be more like "How to use php's variables in javascript?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flavio is right here. You need to change your PHP code.

For example, change the PHP code to return, say, JSON of the result of sending a GET request, which would be the result of the SQL query.

Then, in Polymer, create a component that calls that via Ajax. The component could update the aforementioned query from input values without need for a page refresh, including initially getting values from URL parameters.

Comment: probably I have found a solution: I set properties as arrays that are returned with ajax calls  where I do sql queries I need... thanks for idea :)

Comment: I have finished now to recode the page... now it works perfectly!! :)

Comment: Glad my suggestion helped. Congrats.